# input range filter for a data in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap

All I want filter for my data to show all my wine above the value that I have to put in my input range. What I should write in my own javascript and also html?

So I used this king of data:

```
 "wine": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "image": "../image/wine1.png",
                "name": "wine1",
                "price": 115000,
                "pts": 12000
                },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "image": "../image/wine2.png",
                "name": "wine2",
                "price": 120000,
                "pts": 10000

            }
]
```

and I used this html:

```
  <input type="range" min="0" max="300000"     />

  <div  ng-repeat="wine in wines ">
                    <img ng-src="{{wine.image}}"  />
                    <p >{{wine.name | uppercase}}</p>
                    <p>{{wine.price | number}} LBP</p>
                    <p >{{wine.pts | number}} PTS</p>

                </div>
```

Comment: you need to create sub array by your filter range and then you can use that sub array in your ng-repeat

Comment: that is the question .. HOW?

Answer (score 3):

Just add model to your input value and pass the model to filter directive like following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>  
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="validateCtrl">
<input type="range" min="0" max="300000" ng-model="search"/>

  <div  ng-repeat="wine in wines | filter:search">
                    <img ng-src="{{wine.image}}"  />
                    <p >{{wine.name | uppercase}}</p>
                    <p>{{wine.price | number}} LBP</p>
                    <p >{{wine.pts | number}} PTS</p>

  </div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('validateCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.wines =  [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "image": "../image/wine1.png",
                "name": "wine1",
                "price": 115000,
                "pts": 12000
                },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "image": "../image/wine2.png",
                "name": "wine2",
                "price": 300000,
                "pts": 10000

            },
             {
                "id": 2,
                "image": "../image/wine2.png",
                "name": "wine2",
                "price": 120000,
                "pts": 10000

            }
]
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: should i put min and max in a scope?? because i want to put from 0 till 13000 for example

Answer (score 2):

To filter price, use as follow:

```
<input ng-model="range.price" min="0" max="300000" value="2500"    />

<div  ng-repeat="wine in wines | filter:search">
    <img ng-src="{{wine.image}}"  />
    <p >{{wine.name | uppercase}}</p>
    <p>{{wine.price | number}} LBP</p>
    <p >{{wine.pts | number}} PTS</p>
</div>
```

Comment: and javascript?

Comment: That's angularjs code, that you don't need to do anything. AngularJS will handle it as to filter list as you typed in that input box.

Comment: anw  ng-model="search.price"  **********

Comment: I've pointed you out how to do it. Pls don't forgot to upvote and mark as correct answer if did well.